# Forms submit не работает в Chrome, ie

Tags: javascript

Есть куча форм с уникальным id

```
<form id='fu_edit_1' method='post' action=''>
....
</form>

<form id='fu_edit_2' method='post' action=''>
....
</form>
```

в определенном месте вызывается такой Js

```
var formName = 'fu_edit_'+id;
document.forms[formName].submit();
```

такой вот код отлично работает в ff последний версии, а в chrome и ie работать отказался.  Однако если указать id формы напрямую все работает, т.е. типа

```
document.forms["fu_edit_2"].submit();
```

Что не так ?

Comment: а что говорит консоль ошибок?

Comment: Совсем вылетело из головы)) В консольке хрома 
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'submit'

Comment: А что, getElementById в хроме и ие тоже не работает?)

Comment: Ну почему же, работает.
document.getElementById('fu_edit_'+id).submit();
Решает проблему))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тогда советую вызвать alert(formName) перед document.forms[formName].submit(); потому что такой код работает:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function test(){
id=2;
var formName = 'fu_edit_'+id;
document.forms[formName].submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id='fu_edit_1' method='post' action=''>
....
</form>

<form id='fu_edit_2' method='post' action=''>
....
</form>
<a href='#' onclick="test();">test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

так что дело скорее всего в том что или не уникальный айдюк или id а от него и formName не тот что надо.

и, не уверен, но **document.forms[formName**] вроде работает не по **id** а по **name**!

Comment: id уникальный, и тот что надо, я побывал выводить через alert, не знаю почему не работало. Впрочем это уже не так важно, с getElementById работает нормально.

Comment: Попробуйте пожалуйста указать у <form name='fu_edit_ ... ради спортивного интереса :-)

Comment: Побывал, не работает так :)

Comment: Беда явно в какой-то мелочи :-(